# Installing Perforce client on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, perforce

I am trying to install perforce on my Ubuntu machine, after I untar the `.tgz` file, I get two folders `lib` and `bin`. Where would be the executable or how do I install it correctly?

Answer (score 15):

It's actually pretty easy, you just copy (or move) everything in the `bin` directory to `/usr/bin` and everything in the `lib` directory to `/usr/lib` (recursively):

```
tar xvfz p4v.tgz
cd p4v-2010.2.317255
sudo cp bin/* /usr/bin/
sudo cp -r lib/* /usr/lib/
```

Comment: If you don't have superuser or sudo rights, you can do a similar thing, but copy to `/home/yourname/bin/` and `/home/yourname/lib`, or whatever is in your path.

Comment: That's a horrible idea!

Answer (score 8):

#### Don't mess with `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib`

The above is a really bad advice; you'll likely screw up the system or get breakage on future updates.

Instead, follow the official Perforce guide https://www.perforce.com/perforce-packages

```
wget -qO - https://package.perforce.com/perforce.pubkey | sudo apt-key add -

printf "deb http://package.perforce.com/apt/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) release\n" \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/perforce.list

sudo apt update && sudo apt install helix-cli
```

The client tools are installed now.

Run `p4v` for the GUI.

Comment: The client `.deb` packages delivered by Perforce include only `p4`. Not `p4v`. You can check it by `dpkg -L helix-cli helix-cli-base`. So, `p4v` still hast be installed by unpacking the `.tgz`. But you should do it in `/usr/local`, which is supposed to contain packages not coming from the distro.

Comment: @FerdinandPrantl the -cli suffix in the package name is supposed to hint that it's the [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)-only package; GUI package would be named differently. But it seems you're right — the `p4v` GUI is not packaged in `.deb` format, neither in `.rpm`... I agree, the `.tgz` tarball should be unpacked to `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 0):

'Bin' is usually short for 'Binary', which is where most executables are stored. Do an 'ls' in the unzipped parent directory to see if there are files titled similar to "INSTALL.txt" or "README.txt."

If it is a precompiled standalone executable (you might check the site where you downloaded it from for instructions), you should just be able to run it by 'cd'ing to the 'bin' directory and then running `./<EXECUTABLENAME>`

Answer (score 0):

After unpacking set up with

```
cp -r <package>/bin/* /usr/bin
cp -r <package>/lib/* /usr/lib
chmod +x /usr/bin/p4v 
chmod +x /usr/bin/p4v.bin
chmod +x /usr/bin/p4admin 
chmod +x /usr/bin/p4admin.bin 
chmod +x /usr/bin/p4merge
chmod +x /usr/bin/p4merge.bin
chmod +x /usr/bin/p4vc
```

Then run with

```
/usr/bin/p4v
```